# using angular filter to sort object by detecting type

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-filter

I was trying to write a filter after reading this: [custom angular filter](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters)

At first it looked easy, but I've run into this problem.

**I want to sort the array of object by detecting the type and display that sorted list in select option value.**

You can see the different array objects and my code here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5PJrr/47/).

The value of **age** can be of these types:

**1)** number

```
$scope.userDetails = [
    {"id":"1","name":"Name1","age":"20"},{"id":"2","name":"Name2","age":"5"},
    {"id":"5","name":"Name3","age":"15"},{"id":"4","name":"Name4", "age":"1"},
    {"id":"3","name":"Name5","age":"101"},{"id":"6","name":"Name6", "age":"51"},
];
```

**2)** string

```
$scope.userDetails = [
    {"id":"1","name":"Name1","age":"ten"},{"id":"2","name":"Name2","age":"hundred"},
    {"id":"4","name":"Name3","age":"six"},{"id":"6","name":"Name4", "age":"one"},
    {"id":"5","name":"Name5","age":"seven"},{"id":"3","name":"Name6", "age":"hundred and one"},
];
```

**3)** both(have both string and number type)

```
$scope.userDetails = [
    {"id":"3","name":"Name1","age":"20"},{"id":"1","name":"Name2","age":"hundred"},
    {"id":"5","name":"Name3","age":"six"},{"id":"2","name":"Name4", "age":"1"},
    {"id":"6","name":"Name5","age":"seven"},{"id":"4","name":"Name6", "age":"hundred and one"},
];
```

I wanted to have an select options sorted by number if the different age values are number type only, and if not then I want to sort by string.

Thank you

**Edit: 1**
I think my question might have confused some of you.I will try to explain it a bit clearly here
for the **(1)** case:
we have only integer value of age **["20","5","15","1","101","51"]** (showing only the age values for each object). Now when I apply filter to sort, It should compare like integer comparison and output should be - **["1","5","15","20","51","101"]** (So I think we have to use regex or parseInt inside filter to convert those to number and compare, But the output should still be in string.)
Input-string, Ouput-string, Comparison-Integer

for the **(2)** case:
we have only integer value of age **["ten", "hundred", "six", "one", "seven", "hundred and one"]** (showing only the age values for each object). Now when I apply filter to sort, It should compare like String comparison and output should be - **["hundred", "hundred and one", "one", "seven", "six", "ten"]** 
Input-string, Ouput-string, Comparison-String

for the **(3)** case:
we have only integer and string value of age **["20", "hundred", "six", "1", "seven", "hundred and one"]** (showing only the age values for each object). Now when I apply filter to sort, It should compare like String comparison and output should be - **["1", "20", "hundred", "hundred and one", "seven", "six"]** 
Input-string, Ouput-string, Comparison-String

Thank you,

Comment: this just seems confusing from UI point of view. would it be possible to convert string type to number?

Comment: no... actually what I wanted to do is
**1)** In case of number. It should treat it as numbers to compare - that is you can use something like parseInt, parseFloat.
_Example:_ "11","5","15" ... should be sorted as - "5", "11" ,"15" **and not as** "11","15","5"
**2)** In case of string, It should perform string comparison - 
_Ex:_ "one","two","sample" ... should be sorted as - "one", "sample","two" **pls note string type comparison**
**3)** both str and number
_Ex:_ "one","two","17","15" ... should be sorted as - "15","17","one", "two" **pls note string type comparison**
Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 1):

Angular has already a filter for sorting. I suggest you don't try to rewrite a sorting filter yourself, but instead write a filter to convert your age props from string to int **ONLY** if all age values can be converted to integers. Note I am using `.map()` and `.some()` which are ES5 functions (you'll need to add a shim if you support IE8).

```
yourModule.filter('tryToConvertAge2Int', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
   // Return filter function
   return function (items) {
      // Check if some age values cannot be converted to integers.
      var notAllIntegers = items
         .some(function (item) {
            return isNan(parseInt(item.age));
         });
      // Return list of items with age props as integers
      // if all values can be converted to integers.
      if (!notAllIntegers) {
         return items.map(function (item) {
            item.age = parseInt(age);
            return item;
         });
      }
      // Otherwise return original items.
      return items;
   };
});
```

Then simply chain `tryToConvertAge2Int` and `orderBy` together:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | tryToConvertAge2Int | orderBy:'+age' track by id"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @thomas-roch for your answer,
But I think you should see the **Edit 1**, I have added some sample for you.

Comment: @govindpatel please review answers.

Comment: Hi @thomas-roch, I tried the one which was provided by you. But I got some error. So I did more search on it... and then I found this: http://blog.overzealous.com/post/55829457993/natural-sorting-within-angular-js . and it worked for me.. 
But your answer actually helped me alot... to understand things.
I remember the error which got was something related to angular.map() not found or something... sorry and thank you for your help.... going to vote your answer. and once Thanks, Thomas for your time.

Comment: Apologies for angular.map. I dunno why I wrote it as it doesn't exist! It should be `items.map`. I have updated my answer.